# python - extract dates from text by giving as parameter the date of reference which is not the current date

Tags: python, date, parsing, nlp

I have some fuzzy text which contain information about dates. For example: 'Concert this Saturday'. I want to extract the date that corresponds to "this Saturday" by **giving the date of reference as parameter.** 
For example, suppose this is a subject of an email sent on 2016-04-13 and I want to get that "this Saturday" that this email was referring to, was on 2016-04-16. Do you know of any package that is able to do that?

P.S.I have used the dateutil.parser but this doesn't take a reference date as a parameter and it gives me as date the following Saturday from the date I'm running the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dateutil.parser.parse` accepts a `default` parameter which you can use to specify a reference date:

```
import datetime as DT
import dateutil.parser as DP

today = DT.datetime(2016, 4, 13)
for text in ('today', 'tomorrow', 'this Sunday', 'Wednesday next week', 
             'next week Wednesday', 
             'next thursday', 'next tuesday in June', '11/28',
             'Concert this Saturday'
             "lunch with Andrew @ Mon Mar 7, 2016",
             'meeting on Tuesday, 3/29'):
    dp_date = DP.parse(text, default=today, fuzzy=True)
    print('{:35} --> {}'.format(text, dp_date))
```

yields

```
today                               --> 2016-04-13 00:00:00
tomorrow                            --> 2016-04-13 00:00:00  should be 2016-04-14
this Sunday                         --> 2016-04-17 00:00:00
Wednesday next week                 --> 2016-04-13 00:00:00
next week Wednesday                 --> 2016-04-13 00:00:00
next thursday                       --> 2016-04-14 00:00:00
next tuesday in June                --> 2016-06-14 00:00:00  should be 2016-06-07
11/28                               --> 2016-11-28 00:00:00
Concert this Saturday               --> 2016-04-16 00:00:00
lunch with Andrew @ Mon Mar 7, 2016 --> 2016-03-07 00:00:00
meeting on Tuesday, 3/29            --> 2016-03-29 00:00:00
```

Note, however, that not all phrases are parsed correctly.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Thanks very much for the improvements.

Comment: Is there any kind of bug when searching events in the past? I gave as input: "last night at the concert" and the same reference_date, and it returns me the date of yesterday as of yesterday referring to today... :/

Comment: I think this is a bug. Even with the latest development version, (installed from [github source](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime)), `parse('last night at the concert', DT.date(2016,4,13))` returns `2016-04-13 21:00:00`, which while better, still seems to be a day off. You may wish to [raise an issue here](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime/issues).

Comment: Unfortunately this library has a lot of bugs. If the text has dates in it then it doesn't work properly. For example I have the following text: "lunch with Andrew @ Mon Mar 7, 2016" and as a reference date "2016-03-06", and it gives me as output : 2016-03-08 13:00:00. How did it calculate this date?
This bug happens with other cases as well: e.g. "meeting on Tuesday, 3/29" and reference date="2016-03-24", gives as output date: 2016-04-03. Do you happen to know any other library?

Comment: Well, there is also `dateutil.parser.parse` which has a `default` parameter for setting a reference date. However, it too incorrectly parses some phrases. I've changed my answer to show what I mean.